# bash command works, but script doesn't despite permissions

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

My script is saved as `recent.sh` and reads currently as:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
rcnt() {
    ls -t -p | grep -v / | head -n1 | cat
}
```

When I `source recent.sh` it and execute `rcnt`, it prints the most recent file in the directory. However, when I `./recent.sh` or `sh recent.sh` it does not print anything to the Terminal. (I try to run it from the directory where it is saved.)

I am trying to run this in Terminal in Linux Mint 19 and I've already tried it with `usr/bin/env bash`, without the -x, with sh instead of bash. Permissions are 777.

How to run this script so that it will print to the Terminal where I executed it?

I'm a beginner, I might be overlooking something, but I read all the relevant SO, StackExchange, etc. answers which mostly recommend setting permissions right, which I believe I have right, the location of bash (which for me is bin/bash) or other code-specific issues.

Comment: You have to call the function you've written . Add " rcnt " in a new line. And also remove the "-x" option in the shebang. It's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @ParsaMousavi! Slowly but surely I am learning that a function needs to be called in order to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function you've wrote in order to execute it.
Function calls in bash don't require parentheses. So your script should look like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
rcnt() {           #Function definition
    ls -t -p | grep -v / | head -n1 | cat
}

rcnt               #Function invocation
```